# Error while uninstalling node

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do a clean sweap of my machine by uninstalling all the modules and node itself. Also, would like to revert back all the config I did like for example setting path variable. Please suggest the best way to do so as I am getting following error while uninstalling node as follows:

```
Command: brew uninstall node
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
Command: node -v
v4.2.2
```

How can i do a clean sweap and start over again.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: It looks like you didn't install node with homebrew, so you'll have to delete the files yourself.

Comment: Nick - Thanks for your reply. How do I do that and also how to install specific version via homebrew?

Comment: Nick - Thanks for your reply. I didnt knew that will cause issues. Can you please help me with steps to remove existing node and re-install node 4.2.2 with brew.

Comment: Run the command from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24611994/1146881 Then do `brew install node`